# php counter on mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach

I got this simple foreach loop and can't figure out where is the problem with counter.

I get results like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2LOf.png). I am trying to make counter enlarged for one if it meets the conditions.

```
$building = 5;
$todaysdate = date("Y-m-d");
$tomorrows_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todaysdate . "+1 days"));
$ends_date = "2018-04-30";

$counter = 0;

$query = "SELECT  *  FROM objekt WHERE vrsta_objekta = '2' ORDER BY sifra ASC"; // results give me numbers from 30 to 110. 
        $querydone = $db->query($query);
        while($row = $querydone->fetch_assoc()) {
            $every_id[$row['sifra']] = $row;
        }

            $firstday = new DateTime($tomorrows_date);
            $lastday = new DateTime($ends_date);

    for($q = $firstday; $q <= $lastday; $q->modify('+1 day')){
                        $result_day = $q->format("Y-m-d");

        $i = 0; // counter for every value from mysql 
        foreach ($every_id as $key => $value) { 

                $counter = ${$i++} = $value['sifra'];
            if($building >= $i) { 
                $valuesResult = "('$result_day','$counter')" . "<br />";
            } else {
                break; 
            }
            echo $valuesResult;
        }

    }
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: We don't know where are you wrong because we don't know what do you expect from your code.

Comment: What is `${$i++}` attempting to do?

Comment: @u_mulder  I am trying to make `$counter` enlarged for one if it meets the conditions.

Comment: `static $counter` might help you.

Comment: @NigelRen counter for every value

Comment: Whats your expected output ? There seems to be problem             
         $counter = ${$i++} = $value['sifra'];

Comment: @Amanjaura, Expected output: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmbzjx74/3/)

Comment: @u_mulder so you are going to help me with my problem or just comment for no reason?

Comment: Wut? I'm not going to fix any problems here unless I want to.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$building = 5;
$todaysdate = date("Y-m-d");
$tomorrows_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($todaysdate . "+1 days"));
$ends_date = "2018-04-30";

$counter = 0;

$query = "SELECT  *  FROM objekt WHERE vrsta_objekta = '2' ORDER BY sifra ASC LIMIT 80"; // results give me numbers from 30 to 110. 
        $querydone = $db->query($query);
        while($row = $querydone->fetch_assoc()) {
            $every_id = $row['sifra'];
        }

            $firstday = new DateTime($tomorrows_date);
            $lastday = new DateTime($ends_date);

    for($q = $firstday; $q <= $lastday; $q->modify('+1 day')){
                        $result_day = $q->format("Y-m-d");

        $i = 0; // counter for every value from mysql 
        foreach ($every_id as $key => $value) { 

                $counter = $i++;
            if($building >= $i) { 
                $valuesResult = "('$result_day','$counter')" . "<br />";
            } else {
                break; 
            }
            echo $valuesResult;
        }

    }
```

Comment: 'Try this and tell me whats the error:' isn't exactly an answer.

Comment: If i set `$every_id = $row['sifra'];` to `$every_id[] = $row['sifra'];` there is no error, and my output is [this](https://imgur.com/2R1RLZI)

Comment: @Pablo yes but I am trying to simplify your code. you can try `LIMIT 80`